# Block Won't Fall After Initial Gravity Effects End

Tags: ios, core-motion, scenekit

I have a simple scene there is a floor, block, camera and light.

The floor is static

```
SCNNode* floor = [SCNNode node];
SCNPhysicsBody *staticBody = [SCNPhysicsBody staticBody];
floor.physicsBody = staticBody;
[[scene rootNode] addChildNode:floor];
```

The block is dynamic

```
SCNNode *block = [SCNNode node];
block.position = SCNVector3Make(-10, 45, -20)
block.geometry = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:5 height:5 length:5 chamferRadius:0];
block.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody dynamicBody];
```

The block's starting position is above the floor, so when the app runs, the block falls to the floor as expected.

I have added motion manager that will move the floor down, simulating the floor being pulled out from under the block by translating negative changes in Y to the block and this is where the trouble begins.

```
if(userAcceleration.y < 0)
{
    SCNVector3 vector = floor.position;
    vector.y += userAcceleration.y*10.0; 
    floor.position = vector;
}
```

If the motion occurs before the block has come to rest, I can shake the device and can keep the block moving around as expected.

However, if the motion occurs after the block has come to a rest for a few seconds, the block will only rise (higher and higher with each motion) above the floor never to fall again.

Why does the gravity affect appear to stop?

Is there something that turns off gravity that I need to checking during the motion check? or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might sound silly, but have you set the `playing` property of your renderer to true?

If that doesn't work, my hack is to add an empty SCNNode and make it rotate forever with a SCNAction. It keeps the scene rendering/calculations going even if nothing is moving.

EDIT: I forgot about the `allowResting` property. It's probably what is causing your problem. Just turn it off for your object!

You can read more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsBody_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNPhysicsBody/allowsResting

Comment: Thanks, looks like it was just a matter of setting `allowResting`